# Reproduce results of bayesglm with stan_glm

Tags: r, bayesian, logistic, prior, stan

As indicated in the title, I am trying to reproduce the
results of the `bayesglm` function with the `stan_glm`. In
principle, the the two functions can perform bayesian
logistic regression, which is useful when data are linearly separated for example.

The `bayesglm` function uses the EM algorithm to provide
point estimates of the unknown parameter as described in
[Gelman et al. (2008)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/priors11.pdf). It uses the t distribution with
1 dof as priors (also known as Cauchy prior). Continuous
predictors are rescaled so that they have a standard
deviation of 0.5. The scale of the t distribution prior is set
to 10 for intercept and to 2.5 for the rescaled predictors.
As a result, the scale for the default prior for a continuous
predictor is:
$$
\lambda = \text{prior.scale} / 2 * \text{sd}(x) 
$$
with `prior.scale` = 2.5.

Here is a full example with data that are linearly separated
and that yields a warning message when fitted with `glm`.

```
library(arm)      # bayesglm
library(rstanarm) # stan_glm

# simulated data set with linear separation
dat <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(0,1,2.5,4,5),each=4),
  y = rep(c(0,1),each=10)
)

# compute proportions 
tmp <- aggregate(dat[,"y",drop=FALSE],dat[,"x",drop=FALSE],mean)
tmp
#     x   y
# 1 0.0 0.0
# 2 1.0 0.0
# 3 2.5 0.5
# 4 4.0 1.0
# 5 5.0 1.0

# fit glm 
fit.glm <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=dat)
# Warning message:
# glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

coef(fit.glm)
# (Intercept)           x 
#   -33.93562    13.57425 

# bayes glm
fit.bglm <- bayesglm(y ~ x, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=dat)
coef(fit.bglm)
# (Intercept)           x 
#   -4.756769    1.902708
```

Additional information on the priors used by `bayesglm`:

```
# prior
tmp <- do.call("rbind",
  fit.bglm[paste0("prior.",c("mean","scale","df","sd"))])
colnames(tmp) <- c("(Intercept)","x")
tmp
#             Intercept         x
# prior.mean   0.000000 0.0000000
# prior.scale 10.000000 0.6607427
# prior.df     1.000000 1.0000000
# prior.sd     7.962467 1.5195179
```

It is easy to verify the scale of the predictor for the
continuous predictor

```
lambda <- 2.5/(2*sd(dat$x))
lambda
# [1] 0.6607427
```

The function `stan_glm` from the `rstanarm` package uses
Markov Chain Monte-Carlo methods to obtain the full posterior
distribution of the parameters.

```
fit.sglm <- stan_glm(y ~ x, data = dat,
   family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
   prior = student_t(df = 1, 0, lambda), 
   prior_intercept = student_t(1, 0, 10),
   cores = 2, seed = 12345)

prior_summary(fit.sglm)
# Intercept (after predictors centered)
#  ~ cauchy(location = 0, scale = 10)    
# Coefficients
#  ~ cauchy(location = 0, scale = 0.66)

print(fit.sglm,digits=5)
#             Median MAD_SD
# (Intercept) -9.407  7.034
# x            3.734  2.731

coef(fit.sglm)
# (Intercept)          x 
#  -9.407408    3.734188
```

The coefficients corresponds to the median of the posterior
distribution. It is also possible to obtain the mean of the
posterior distribution

```
bayestestR::point_estimate(fit.sglm, centrality = "mean")$Mean
# [1] -21.928522   8.766372
```

The results are very different from these obtained with `bayesglm`. I selected this example with a small linearly separated data set to emphasize this differences. I expect
to obtain slightly different values due to the difference in
underlying algorithms but I would not expected such a large
difference if the  priors are the same and the point estimates
are computed correctly. I have tried also to rescale the intercept but it did not help. I would like to know how to reproduce the results of `bayeglm` with `stan_glm` and, if
it is not possible, why.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the model definitions and priors used are exactly the same in both cases?

Comment: I tried to define the `stan_glm` to be equivalent to the `bayesglm` model to the best of my understanding (see linked paper).  When fitting the `stan_glm` model, I used the scale parameter returned by the `bayesglm` fit (i.e. `fit.bglm$prior.scale`) and explained how it was computed. However,   I am not 100% about the scale of the intercept because Gelman et al (2008) write the predictors are first rescaled to have a SD = 0.5 and then the prior is set to 2.5 for the rescaled parameters and 10 for the intercept. If this is true, then the intercept should be scaled differently.

Comment: @gavrill so you should probably first dive to the source code and made them 100% the same with the only difference of the algorithm used for obtaining the results. Otherwise, it is hard to compare the results. If those are different models, than we wouldn't expect the results to be the same, especially if, as you say, the data is not big.

Comment: I have looked in `arm::bayesglm.fit` function, which estimates the model parameters.  Unlike what I understood from the paper, it does not seem to rescale the predictor explicitly and it seems to use the scale parameter returned by the function (i.e., fit.bglm$prior.scale). It is difficult to check prior from the code because they are not simulated but somehow incorporated in the EM algorithm following Raftery (1996) approach (this part above my math abilities).

Comment: The difference between the two results is not purely a question of theoretical interest. In psychophysical experiments, small linearly separated datasets are not uncommon and  Bayesian logistic regression is often recommended to deal with with this problem (e.g. Kuss et al. 2005, JOV). Moreover, I think that using `bayesglm` with uninformative default prior as a stand-in for `glm`  has become quite popular. Since both `bayesglm` and `Stan` are developed by Gelman's group, I hope that somebody with insight in both functions can chime in.

Comment: You could try asking this same question on the Stan Forums. People from Gelman's group (and sometimes Andrew Gelman himself) are active over there and I would expect at least some of them to be familiar with both of these functions. Good luck! https://discourse.mc-stan.org/

Comment: I have indeed received some responses on Stan Forum. Follow  the link
https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/reproduce-results-of-bayesglm-with-stan-glm/
The model specification with `stan_lm` is correct.  The correctness of results however is uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I should refer to the reply to my [question] (https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/reproduce-results-of-bayesglm-with-stan-glm/) in Stan Forum as an answer to this question.
In short, `stan_glm` yields more similar results `bayesglm` if a more restrictive prior is used.